# Are Pokémon depicted dying in a fight?

Tags: pokemon

Pikachu almost fell into lava after a fight with Magmar in an arena above a volcano. Charmander was allowed to fight in a water arena where he could fall into water. It's a deadly sport without safety rules.

Has any Pokémon ever been depicted dying in a fight?

Comment: Yes but I can't find clips to prove it, only bulbapedia links

Answer (score 4):

Not in the show.

Depending how you define a "fight", there are a couple in the tie-in movies, however. If you consider battles between two Pokémon (as it seems you do), but not necessarily battles between two Pokémon *trainers* using their Pokémon to fight each other:

- In *Pokémon 3: The Movie*, the legendary Pokémon Entei sacrifices himself in a battle against a group of Unown in order to break down their combined psychic shield.
- In the sixth movie, *Jirachi: Wish Maker*, the mythical Pokémon Jirachi kills a revived (Jurassic Park-style) giant and evil version of the prehistoric Groudon.

Comment: I think there are additional deaths in the manga, and there are hints at it in the games, but I'm fairly sure that those are all old age or "sacrificing themselves", not as a result of battle. As for your examples, one could argue that _Evil_ Groudon isn't the _real_ Groudon, so it's not clear whether or not it's even alive. Entei, likewise, was created by the Unown, which is why he died when he destroyed their psychic barrier. So there are two main questions to answer: Do Evil Groudon and Entei count as real Pokémon, and are their deaths technically due to "battle"?

Comment: Personally, I'm leaning towards counting Entei, but I'm not sure about Groudon.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo You're not wrong. There are also the simulated "Mirage" versions of Mew and Mewtwo who "kill" each other in battle, but I decided those weren't Pokémon. Entei and the "false" Groudon are arguably a little more real. There are others that sacrifice themselves, but not in a battle against Pokémon (I think).

Comment: Lucario and Latios' sacrifices weren't related to their respective battles, those came afterwards. The rest always get revived after being "killed". Looking into it, Ash actually dies quite a lot. It's a good thing he's so good at befriending Pokémon capable of mass resurrection.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Yeah, exactly, that was why I didn't mention Lucario and Latios.

Comment: I mean there's a pretty good list [here](http://listofdeaths.wikia.com/wiki/Pokemon)

Comment: @Edlothiad Yeah, but most are not really "deaths" and not while "fighting". See mine and DisturbedNeo's comments above.

Comment: [Pikachu is turned to stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByhMm7u-22k) in *Diancie and the Cocoon of Destruction* by a legendary pokemon. Naturally, some other legendary pokemon reverses it shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the continuity.

In general, when two Pokemon battle, it's depicted as friendly competition: a sport, for fun. They aren't actually trying to kill each other, and I would imagine they're holding back to avoid doing so. The out-of-universe reason for Pokemon *fainting* in battle, rather than *dying*, is that the series' creator didn't want it to be too violent.

In the games, there are reference to Pokemon having died - many of the main-series games feature graveyards, not to mention the ghost of Marowak in Lavender Tower - but none are depicted actually dying. There is a fan theory that one of your battles against Blue in RGB/FRLG results in the death of his Raticate - the next time you see him, he's in Lavender Tower, and Raticate isn't in his party - but that's only a *theory*, not canon.

In the anime, it's shown that Pokemon *can* fight to the death, just not in trainer battles. As well as the examples @tobiasvl mentioned, I'd like to highlight the famous "Clones v Originals" battle in *Pokemon: The First Movie*. It's made clear that not only are they actively trying to kill each other (or at least, the clones are trying to kill the originals), but that *Pokemon do not usually fight like that*. The only reason none of them die is because Ash sacrifices himself to stop the fight.

I'm not an expert on the various manga, but as I recall, Pokemon can and do die in battle in them. Certainly they suffer severe physical injuries, such as one of Koga's Arbok getting sliced clean in two (it recovered though - thanks to OP for correcting me on that). It's still, as far as I'm aware, a very rare occurence.

Comment: Koga's Arbok regenerated from that injury.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll do some more research and see if I can find a better example.

Comment: Certainly seems possible enough. Charmander will die if the flame on his tail goes out. With a strong/large enough water attack in a battle, that'd be feasibly possible.

Comment: Oh, it's certainly possible, but that's not the question. The question is whether it's *shown happening*.

Comment: I seem to recall that the attack Self-Destruct causes death in the manga.